# How to rearrange rows and columns of text into one column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, flatten, google-query-language

I would like to take a very large set of rows and columns of cells and rearrange them as one long column. is that possible with a formula?

From this

[image]

to this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(D:G); "where Col1 is not null"; )
```